# split a data.frame by columns using a grouping variable

Tags: r, split, dataframe

It's fairly easy to split a `data.frame` by rows depending on a grouping factor. But how do I split by columns and possibly apply a function?

```
my.df <- data.frame(a = runif(10),
        b = runif(10),
        c = runif(10),
        d = runif(10))
grp <- as.factor(c(1,1, 2,2))
```

What I would like to have is a mean of colums by groups.

What I have so far is a poor man's apply.

```
lapply(as.list(as.numeric(levels(grp))), FUN = function(x, cn, data) {
            rowMeans(data[grp %in% x])
        }, cn = grp, data = my.df)
```

*EDIT*
Thank you all for participating. I ran 10 replicates* and my working data.frame has roughly 22000 rows. These are the results in seconds.

```
Roman: 2.19
Joris: 4.60
Joris #2: 3.79 #changed sapply to lapply as suggested by Joris in the [R chatroom][1].
Gavin: 4.70
James & EDi: > 200 # * ran only one replicate due to the large order of magnitude difference
```

It struck me as odd that there is no wrapper function for the task at hand. Maybe someday we'll be able to do

```
apply(X = my.df, MARGIN = 3, INDEX = my.groups, FUN = mean) # :)
```

Comment: Your data frame has 10 rows, and grp has 4 values.  How are they supposed to match up?

Comment: @hadley : the data frame has 4 columns, and grp has 4 values, so that matches up...

Comment: @hadley, I want to split by columns, not rows, so I should match length(my.df) == length(grp).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same logic, but in a more convenient form :

```
sapply(levels(grp),function(x)rowMeans(my.df[which(grp==x)]))
```

Comment: That version is ~x2 faster than the one I showed Joris. Indexing usually is. +1

Answer (score 5):

Convert `my.df` to a list and split that, then apply your function to each subset of components of the list, after coercing to a data frame:

```
lapply(split(as.list(my.df), grp), function(x) rowMeans(as.data.frame(x)))
```

This gives:

```
> lapply(split(as.list(my.df), grp), function(x) rowMeans(as.data.frame(x)))
$`1`
 [1] 0.8229189 0.4901288 0.2057578 0.6531641 0.3897858 0.4225179
 [7] 0.3905410 0.3928784 0.1715857 0.3973192

$`2`
 [1] 0.61348623 0.61229702 0.31938521 0.28325342 0.25857158
 [6] 0.49071991 0.01179999 0.57639186 0.38407240 0.17467337
```

Which is equivalent to @Roman's "poor man's apply":

```
> roman <- lapply(as.list(as.numeric(levels(grp))), 
+                 FUN = function(x, cn, data) {
+                     rowMeans(data[grp %in% x])
+                 }, cn = grp, data = my.df)
> gavin <- lapply(split(as.list(my.df), grp), 
+                 function(x) rowMeans(as.data.frame(x)))
> all.equal(roman, gavin)
[1] "names for current but not for target"
```

except for the names on the components.

Comment: This method silently ignores the fact that the grp vector is not the right length.

Comment: @hadley what is not the right length? `grp` is of length 4 and `as.list(my.df)` is also of length 4. Why is this not the equivalent of `split(1:4, grp)`? A list is a vector after all.

Comment: @hadley given your comment to the Q, I think you've misunderstood what was required.

Comment: @hadley no probs - had me doubting myself for a minute there! If your's was the downvote (no worries if it was) then my recent minor edit should allow you to undo if you wish :-)

Comment: I don't understand why stackoverflow has to lock in your vote - it often takes me more than 2 hours to realise I was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Is this working?

```
aggregate(t(my.df), list(grp), mean)
```

Comment: This method silently ignores the fact that the grp vector is not the right length.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
my.df2 <- data.frame(t(my.df),grp)
aggregate(.~grp,my.df2,mean)
```

Comment: Sorry, but this solution takes too much time on my working data set (see my updated answer).